# How to search for emails to filter by not-in-the-subject?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like to see if there is a way to search for outlook emails which the passing text doesn't not belong to the emails ex:

```
emails:
from:person-a to:person-b subject:something-nice
from:person-a to:person-b subject:something-ok
```

I filter:

```
subject:not(ok)
```

it should return the below only:

```
from:person-a to:person-b subject:something-nice
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing in my outlook lab, you could filter messages via using below criteria:

```
NOT subject:ok
```

It should return all messages don't include "ok".

For more details: [Learn to narrow your search criteria for better searches in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da)